# Swift Error initializing array/dictionary of embedded type

Tags: swift, collections

```
struct SomeStruct {
    struct AnotherStruct {
        var int: Int
    }

    var int: Int
}


var someArray = [SomeStruct.AnotherStruct]()  // error
var anotherArray = Array<SomeStruct.AnotherStruct>()  // this works
```

For the code above, I get a 
`cannot call value of non-function type '[SomeStruct.AnotherStruct.Type]'`. Is this a bug or something that we're stuck with, so we have to use the Array notation?

Comment: You need to write like as let arr = [SomeStruct.AnotherStruct.self].

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and raise at `bugs.swift.org` [SR349](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-349) . you also can't declare empty array of nested class using this.

```
var someArray = [SomeClass.AnotherClass]()  // error
```

You can use this syntax to declare empty array of struct inside struct like this

```
 var someArray: [SomeStruct.AnotherStruct] = []
```

Comment: True, but `[Type]()` is my favorite notation... I can only think this is a bug.

Comment: yes! this is a bug. i'm also not able to create epmty array of class inside class using this syntax.